# PHP-FPM Exporter Binary can not access php unix socket

Tags: php, linux, unix-socket

I am using the binary of https://github.com/hipages/php-fpm_exporter to try to export php metrics to Prometheus. One of the parameters you can set is the unix socket in question. Here are the permissions on my PHP unix socket:

`srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Sep  8 15:17 /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`

and this is what happens when I try running the binary:

```
admin@1234567:~$ sudo -u www-data bash -c "./php-fpm_exporter_2.2.0_linux_amd64 get --phpfpm.scrape-uri unix:///var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock" 
ERRO[0000] Pool[unix:///var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock]: Access denied. 
ERRO[0000] invalid character 'A' looking for beginning of value 
ERRO[0000] invalid character 'A' looking for beginning of value 
Address:                unix:///var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
Pool:                                                      
Start time:             Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000    
Start since:            0                                  
Accepted connections:   0                                  
Listen Queue:           0                                  
Max Listen Queue:       0                                  
Listen Queue Length:    0                                  
Idle Processes:         0                                  
Active Processes:       0                                  
Total Processes:        0                                  
Max active processes:   0                                  
Max children reached:   0                                  
Slow requests:          0
```

Can someone explain why it can't access the unix socket, and what the other errors are about invalid character 'A'?

As an FYI - this is my location block in my nginx file:

```
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
```

The website works fine, so the socket clearly is functional. You'll notice that the socket in this file is listed as `unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;`. I have tried that in my command and that didn't work. I tried `unix:///var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;/status` and `unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;/status`, all the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the 'Access Denied' message was a bit misleading. I found in my PHP FPM pool.d/www.conf file that I had the following set:

`pm.status_path = /php_fpm_status`

Thus, the path was NOT /status but /php_fpm_status. When I updated my command with this, it worked.

Here is my final working command:

`./php-fpm_exporter_2.2.0_linux_amd64 get --phpfpm.scrape-uri "unix:///var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;/php_fpm_status"`